# Pass related sobject subobject from record flow to apex action

Tags: apexactionfunction

So in Record triggered flows you can get `{$Record}` and pass that but is there a way I can pass `{$Record.Account}` as an Account object? As when you send just `{$Record}` it strips the related object requiring either a SOQl query or to manually copy all fields over to a new object within the flow which makes maintainability not ideal.